# Specific user have rights to edit for spefic hours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am user of google spreadsheet. There are 95 users of spreadsheet, From that 23 people have rights to edit the sheet.

I want to do for 3 people that from 9:30 am to 7:30 pm, they can edit the sheet. After that, their rights turn to view only?

Is there any luck with this question's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **yes**, read the related documentation about [protections](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) and [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and experiment.  If you meet any difficulties feel free to show your attempts and ask further help.

Comment: Can i have script? Because i am a normal person and not a developer to understand the script.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask for ready made code, maybe you can get that on the Google + community : https://plus.google.com/u/1/communities/102471985047225101769